options for loading mnist dataset in python
I am confused about the options for loading data into python. Using the mnist dataset, I have found numerous options for loading the test and trainsets. Since these options are tethered to the tutorial associated with each way to load the data, I am interested in how to make these different load interchangable. As an example, the code in https://github.com/tschechlovdev/AutoEncoder_KMeans/blob/main/AutoEncoder_KMeans_MNIST.ipynb
uses
trainset = MNIST('./', download=True, train=True,transform=transform) testset = MNIST('./', download=True,train=False,transform=transform) 
However the raw mnist data can also be loaded and processed using https://rpubs.com/JanpuHou/465274
My question is whether there is Python code that will make these datasets interchangeable?
After reading various blogs I have taken the above test/train datasets, converted them to panda dataframes, exported as CSV and loaded using pd.read_csv. Unfortunately this process does not get me back to the original trainset and testset formats obtained using MNIST as above.
Could anyone explain whether this is possible, and if so, how? My overall objective is to mimic the MNIST data with my own. I would add that I am totally confused about attributes, class, property assignments in python, despite the numerous blogs on the topic.
The strategy on converting to a Panda dataframe failed. In other words, the data could be successfully written to a CSV file, then read (od.read_csv).
But their format has changed.

Can you be more precise what "interchangeable" means for you?

Perhaps a poor word choice. I would like to export the mnist dataset as a csv then import the same dataset so it will be identical to the original mnist data. As a example,

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, as_frame=True) can be used to load the complete dataset. The task is to export this data as a csv file, then import the csv dataset in a form identical to the original mnist dataset. I have tried loading the mnist dataset with and withoupt panda formating ((as.frame=True/False)

As a test I am using the code in

https://jovian.ai/1potdish/mnist-tsne

Can you edit your question to be more precise and explain how you load the data, how you export it and what's the problem with the reimport. maybe some arguments are missing for pandas, hard to tell.
